# Fast way to creating a word-occurrence counting vector

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap<String, Integer> vocabulary`, containing words and their weight (not important, only the string is important here):

```
   vocabulary = ["this movie"=5, "great"=2, "bad"=2, ...]
```

and a tokenized string as a list:

```
String str = "this movie is great";
List<String> tokens = tokenize(str) // tokens = ["this", "movie", "is", "great", "this movie", "is great", ...]
```

Now I need a fast way to create a vector for this tokenized string, that counts for every entry of the vocabulary, the number of occurrences of this word within the tokenized string

```
HashMap<String, Integer> vec = new HashMap();
Iterator it = vocabulary.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
   String word = (String) pair.getKey();
   int count = 0;
   for (String w : tokens) {
      if (w.equals(word)) {
         count += 1;
      }
   }
   vec.put(word, count);
}
```

So, `vec` should be `["this movie"=1, "great"=1, bad = 0]`

Is there a better performing way to do this? I'm having performance issues in a larger context and assumed that the issue must be here, since vocabulary has approximately 300'000 entries. A normal tokenized text contains around 100 words.

Is it a problem that vocabulary is a hashMap?

Comment: do you experience performance issues? or do you just think that your approach is slow?

Comment: Yes I do have performance issues. In my cases, vocabulary contains 300k entries and the tokens maybe 1000.

Comment: Have you tried having your vocabulary list ordered so you can do faster search in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the number of occurrences of each element of `tokens`:

```
Map<String, Long> tokensCount = tokens.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Then just look up from this map instead of your inner loop:

```
count = tokensCount.getOrDefault(word, 0L).intValue();
```

This is faster because the lookup in the map is O(1), whereas iterating the `tokens` looking for equal elements is O(# tokens).

---

Also note that you aren't using `pair` other than to get its key, so you can iterate `vocabulary.keySet()`, rather than `vocabulary.entrySet()`.

Additionally, if you weren't using a raw iterator, you wouldn't need the explicit casts:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = ...
```

---

Edit, now that you've added the relative sizes of the two collections:

You can simply iterate `tokens`, and see if `vocabulary` contains that:

```
Map<String, Integer> vec = new HashMap<>();
for (String token : tokens) {
  if (vocabulary.contains(token)) {
    vec.merge(token, 1, (old,v) -> old+v);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are still looping through the whole `vocabulary`, which is the largest collection of both

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, replacing the for loop with your first line gives me `Incompatible types. Required Map<String, Long> but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Long conforms to Map<String,Long> inference variable R has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Long upper bounds: Object, Map<String, Long>` Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If `vocabulary` is already a `HashMap`, there is no need to iterate over it. Simply use the method `contains` which, in the case of the `HashMap`, is constant (O(1)), so you only have to iterate over the token list.

```
for(String w : tokens) {
    if(vocabulary.contains(w)) {
        vec.put(w, vec.get(w) + 1);
    }
}
```